# Facebook Invite Acceptance Rate dropping and steeper decline

Tags: apprequests

Our app is having an issue with Invite Acceptance Rate, and I'm trying to find out if anyone is experiencing a similar problem.  We had an app update mid-December, and there was about a 70% drop, and then started coming back up- only to decline again after the first of the year.

We had been using the REquest 2.0 framework for some time, but our setting "Upgrade to Request 2.0" setting was disabled.  This was fixed over the wknd, but that still wouldnt have explained the initial drop mid-December since the Request 2.0 migration was not enforced until the first of the year.

We've looked at several features in the past app update but nothing seems to be the root cause.  Any ideas? Or anyone experience a similar issue?

Comment: While related to programming, perhaps this might be better addressed to Facebook? I don't really see a programming problem to solve here. The behavior you describe is odd enough to indicate that there might _be_ one, so I'm not casting a moderator close vote. However, if you could edit this to be more specific.. do you suspect anything in particular? Any possible test case? It would help.